# Deploying smart contract programatically from web3 / nodejs

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, nodejs

I'm building a Dapp where, whenever a user creates an account, it automatically creates an Ethereum address for the user (I'm exposing the personal module over RPC for now, but it's just for playing purposes). I now want to automatically deploy a contract when a user creates an account, ideally to make that user the only address capable of interacting with that contract.

Following some tutorials ([this](http://hypernephelist.com/2016/12/13/compile-deploy-ethereum-smart-contract-web3-solc.html)), I installed solc and changed my code to

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
const solc = require('solc');
var fs = require('fs');
const input = fs.readFileSync('contracts/helloWorld.sol');
const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
const bytecode = output.contracts['helloWorld'].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':helloWorld'].interface);
```

This however, throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property ':helloWorld' of undefined`. After some investigation, I realised the output is returning `{ errors: [ ':1:1: Error: Expected import directive or contract definition.\npragma solidity ^0.4.11;\n^\n' ] }`

Finally, even after seeing [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6562/what-is-the-cause-of-the-error-expected-import-directive-or-contract-definition) answer, I still can't figure out why. I paste my contract code on Remix IDE and it does not throw any error.

My contract code (the test one I'm using now) is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract helloWorld {
    /* Constructor */
    address owner;

    function helloWorld() {
        owner = msg.sender;    
    }

    function remove() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            // Suicide and send funds to owner
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }

    function greet() constant returns (bytes32, address) {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            bytes32 hello = "hello";
            return (hello, msg.sender);
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, been stuck for a while :)

Comment: Check compilation results for errors  **if (output['errors']) {  console.log(JSON.stringify(output['errors']))}**

Comment: Is it necessary to read the contract from a file? if contract is not changing you can avoid onfly compilation.

Comment: It would be more convenient because that way I could have contracts directory as part of the node app with all contracts in it. But what would you propose as the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just cutting and pasting your code into the nodejs terminal (note the grave ticks) so...

```
var source = `pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract helloWorld {
    /* Constructor */
    address owner;

    function helloWorld() {
        owner = msg.sender;    
    }

    function remove() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            // Suicide and send funds to owner
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }

    function greet() constant returns (bytes32, address) {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            bytes32 hello = "hello";
            return (hello, msg.sender);
        }
    }

}`

var output = solc.compile(source);
```

The import stuff is all sorts of weird still for me too

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an encoding issue. https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/90

Your error message comes from this line: `\npragma solidity ^0.4.11;\n^\n'`

When I ran it in my console, the toString resulted in `\npragma solidity ^0.4.11;\n\n`, so I think the `\n^` literal is causing solc to mess up.

Comment: The error is coming from that line but I didn't quite get how to solve it from your answer, could you clarify please?

Comment: Also, I've tried using npm utf8 package to convert to UTF-8 but it returned an error as well.

Comment: The person in the link I sent fixed his issue by adjusting the encoding in the editor itself, as importing with utf8 encoding using fs didn't work. I think the issue might be with your editor, because your code worked for me perfectly.

Comment: I'm using Sublime 2 and have tried File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8 and it still gives me the same error. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @thefett's answer worked for me as well... maybe update solc?

Comment: I'm at version `0.4.13+commit.0fb4cb1a.Emscripten.clang` which one are you using?

Comment: 0.4.4+commit.4633f3de.Darwin.appleclang

Comment: Turns out I was making a stupid mistake. I was testing solc in a different Terminal window and not in my node app. Turns out the solc module was not installed in the node app (too many hours with this). Now it's working, thanks a lot for the help and sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

using solc version 0.4.19, Contract object can be accesible by adding `:` prefix to the contract name,

`const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
const bytecode = '0x' + output.contracts[':helloWorld'].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':helloWorld'].interface);`